# Applying image style to Privatemsg

Tags: media, privatemsg

Drupal 7: Privatemsg.

The following statement, when included in the *privatemsg-view.tpl.php* template prints the author's picture:

```
print theme('user_picture', array('account' => $message->author));
```

How do I modify it to include an image style?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is off the top of my head with some parts but I think this is the way you would do it.

`print theme('image_style', array('path' => $message->author->picture->uri, 'style_name' => '{image-style}'));`

With {image-style} replaced with image style that you want like thumbnail.

If this doesn't work I will take a second look.

Comment: Bravo @burnsjeremy, that was not an easy one, but you got it right! Thanks a million. :)